# [rplidarNode-6] process has died

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am trying to run this, `roslaunch evarobot_slam evarobot_slam.launch` but when I do I get an error. Any ideas?

```
metobom@metobom-TULPAR-T5-V17-1:~$ roslaunch evarobot_slam evarobot_slam.launch
WARNING: Package name "metosPack" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
... logging to /home/metobom/.ros/log/008a4e1e-32cd-11e9-a3aa-b46bfc3ecfa1/roslaunch-metobom-TULPAR-T5-V17-1-11657.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

WARNING: Package name "metosPack" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
 old: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro
 new: http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro (/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/evapc_ros/evarobot_description/urdf/evarobot_base.urdf.xacro)
redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/metobom/metos_ws/src/evapc_ros/evarobot_description/urdf/evarobot.urdf.xacro
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
 old: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro
 new: http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro (/home/metobom/metos_ws/src/evapc_ros/evarobot_description/urdf/evarobot_base.urdf.xacro)
redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/metobom/metos_ws/src/evapc_ros/evarobot_description/urdf/evarobot.urdf.xacro
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://metobom-TULPAR-T5-V17-1:35549/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/controller/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_controller
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/controller/path: Controller
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/controller/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/controller/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/motor/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_driver
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/motor/path: Motor
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/motor/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/motor/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/bumper/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_bumper
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/bumper/path: Bumper
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/bumper/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/bumper/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/imu/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_minimu9
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/imu/path: IMU
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/imu/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/imu/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/infrared/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_infrared
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/infrared/path: Infrared
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/infrared/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/infrared/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/odom/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_odometry
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/odom/path: Odom
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/odom/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/odom/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/sonar/find_and_remove_prefix: evarobot_sonar
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/sonar/path: sonar
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/sonar/timeout: 5.0
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/analyzers/sonar/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/path: Sensors
 * /diag_agg/analyzers/sensors/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /hector_height_mapping/advertise_map_service: True
 * /hector_height_mapping/base_frame: base_link
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_pub_period: 0.25
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_resolution: 0.1
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_size: 100
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_start_x: 0.5
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_start_y: 0.5
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_update_angle_thresh: 0.1
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_update_distance_thresh: 0.02
 * /hector_height_mapping/map_with_known_poses: False
 * /hector_height_mapping/odom_frame: odom_combined
 * /hector_height_mapping/output_timing: False
 * /hector_height_mapping/pub_map_odom_transform: True
 * /hector_height_mapping/scan_topic: lidar
 * /hector_height_mapping/update_factor_free: 0.45
 * /hector_height_mapping/use_tf_pose_start_estimate: False
 * /hector_height_mapping/use_tf_scan_transformation: True
 * /joint_state_publisher/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /joint_state_publisher/use_gui: False
 * /master_discovery/active_request_after: 60
 * /master_discovery/change_notification_count: 3
 * /master_discovery/heartbeat_hz: 0.02
 * /master_discovery/interface: 
 * /master_discovery/log_level: INFO
 * /master_discovery/mcast_group: 224.0.0.0
 * /master_discovery/mcast_port: 11511
 * /master_discovery/measurement_intervals: 5
 * /master_discovery/remove_after: 300
 * /master_discovery/robot_hosts: []
 * /master_discovery/rosmaster_hz: 1
 * /master_discovery/rpc_port: 11611
 * /master_discovery/send_mcast: True
 * /master_discovery/timeout_factor: 1.4
 * /master_sync/ignore_hosts: []
 * /master_sync/ignore_nodes: ['/rplidarNode']
 * /publish_frequency: 10.0
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_pose_ekf/base_footprint_frame: base_link
 * /robot_pose_ekf/debug: False
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq: 50.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame: odom_combined
 * /robot_pose_ekf/self_diagnose: True
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout: 1.0
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used: True
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /rplidarNode/angle_compensate: True
 * /rplidarNode/frame_id: lidar_link
 * /rplidarNode/inverted: True
 * /rplidarNode/serial_baudrate: 115200
 * /rplidarNode/serial_port: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /tf_prefix: /

NODES
  /
    diag_agg (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
    hector_height_mapping (hector_mapping/hector_mapping)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    master_discovery (master_discovery_fkie/master_discovery)
    master_sync (master_sync_fkie/master_sync)
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    rplidarNode (rplidar_ros/rplidarNode)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

WARNING: Package name "metosPack" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
process[master_discovery-1]: started with pid [11684]
process[master_sync-2]: started with pid [11685]
process[robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [11686]
process[joint_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [11687]
process[robot_pose_ekf-5]: started with pid [11697]
process[rplidarNode-6]: started with pid [11716]
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
process[hector_height_mapping-7]: started with pid [11726]
process[diag_agg-8]: started with pid [11731]
RPLIDAR running on ROS package rplidar_ros
SDK Version: 1.5.7
Error, cannot bind to the specified serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
[WARN] [1550419387.889904, 142.059000]: Master_discovery node appear not to running. Wait for topic with type 'MasterState.
HectorSM map lvl 0: cellLength: 0.1 res x:100 res y: 100
HectorSM map lvl 1: cellLength: 0.2 res x:50 res y: 50
HectorSM map lvl 2: cellLength: 0.4 res x:25 res y: 25
[ INFO] [1550419387.914145784, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_base_frame_: base_link
[ INFO] [1550419387.914208743, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_map_frame_: map
[ INFO] [1550419387.914285308, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_odom_frame_: odom_combined
[ INFO] [1550419387.914301138, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_scan_topic_: lidar
[ INFO] [1550419387.914315614, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_use_tf_scan_transformation_: true
[ INFO] [1550419387.914329710, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_pub_map_odom_transform_: true
[ INFO] [1550419387.914342660, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_scan_subscriber_queue_size_: 5
[ INFO] [1550419387.914357817, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_map_pub_period_: 0.250000
[ INFO] [1550419387.914371499, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_update_factor_free_: 0.450000
[ INFO] [1550419387.914386448, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_update_factor_occupied_: 0.900000
[ INFO] [1550419387.914398388, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_map_update_distance_threshold_: 0.020000 
[ INFO] [1550419387.914434465, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_map_update_angle_threshold_: 0.100000
[ INFO] [1550419387.914461370, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_laser_z_min_value_: -1.000000
[ INFO] [1550419387.914487060, 142.078000000]: HectorSM p_laser_z_max_value_: 1.000000
[rplidarNode-6] process has died [pid 11716, exit code 255, cmd /home/metobom/metos_ws/src/evapc_ros/evapc_start/scripts/lidar_permission /home/metobom/metos_ws/devel/lib/rplidar_ros/rplidarNode scan:=lidar __name:=rplidarNode __log:=/home/metobom/.ros/log/008a4e1e-32cd-11e9-a3aa-b46bfc3ecfa1/rplidarNode-6.log].
log file: /home/metobom/.ros/log/008a4e1e-32cd-11e9-a3aa-b46bfc3ecfa1/rplidarNode-6*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315854/%5Brplidarnode-6%5D-process-has-died/) by [metobom](https://answers.ros.org/users/39588/metobom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the rplidar_ros package cannot bind the /dev/ttyUSB0 port:

```
RPLIDAR running on ROS package rplidar_ros
SDK Version: 1.5.7
Error, cannot bind to the specified serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
```

Check if you have permission to read/write serial ports (your user must be in "dialout" group), or if the sensor has been assigned to another port (e.g., /dev/ttyUSB1).

[This question](https://answers.ros.org/question/199561/rplidar-driver-installation-problem-on-ubuntu/) might also help you.

---

Originally posted by [renangm](https://answers.ros.org/users/17986/renangm/) with karma: 183 on 2019-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0